# Error al usar comando bcp con xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Estoy intentando usar el comando bcp mediante una query con xp_cmdshell el problema esque al ejecutarlo me salta un error de No se puede abrir el archivo. Pero si ejecuto lo mismo por lineas de comandos funciona perfectamente. El usuario que estoy usando tiene permisos de sysadmin

```
  exec xp_cmdshell 'bcp "Prueba.dbo.tabla" out "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\prueba.txt" -c -T -t -r'
```

El error que me muestra es este

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El error es por tema de permisos, lo que he hecho para que me funcione es ejecutar la query `exec master..xp_cmdshell 'whoami'` y te dice el usuario con el ejecuta el comando, lo que hay que hacer es añadirle permisos a ese usuario a la carpeta que quieres acceder.

Si no funciona se puede cambiar el usuario con el que inicia sesión sql server en panel de control > Herramientas administrativas > Servicios > Buscar Sql Server (En mi caso SQL Server MSSQLSERVER) > en la pestaña inicio de sesión poner el que se quiera